# How can I update/reload/refresh a section header view in a UITableView?

Tags: uitableview, header

I'm willing to change a specific header view of my UITableView when I click a row.

I've read **all** posts about it yet. I tried "reloadData", "setNeedDisplay", "reloadSections:withRowAnimation:", and several others ideas... there is nothing to do. My header view either doesn't update or it does weird things like updating only when I move the table view (which is not what I'm willing to achieve).

My code looks like this for now (regarding the UITableView delegates methods):

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView*)tableView {
    if(tableView==_storeTableView){
        return [_storeDataArray count];
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if(tableView==_storeTableView){
        HouraStoreHeaderModel *headerModel = [self.headerInfoArray objectAtIndex:section];
        if (!headerModel.headerView) {
            NSString *shelfName = headerModel.shelf;
            headerModel.headerView = [[[HouraStoreHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, _storeTableView.bounds.size.width, 80) title:shelfName section:section subheaderNumber:([headerModel.openedSubHeaders count]-1) delegate:self] autorelease];
        }
        return headerModel.headerView;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if(tableView==_storeTableView){
        HouraStoreHeaderModel *headerModel = [self.headerInfoArray objectAtIndex:section];
        NSDictionary *myDict = _storeDataDict;
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [headerModel.openedSubHeaders count]; i++) {
            myDict = [myDict objectForKey:[headerModel.openedSubHeaders objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
        NSInteger numberOfRowsInSection = [[myDict allKeys] count];
        return headerModel.open ? numberOfRowsInSection : 0;
    } else if(tableView==_searchTableView){
        return [_resultArray count];
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    if(tableView==_storeTableView){
        HouraStoreHeaderModel *headerModel = [self.headerInfoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        NSDictionary *myDict = _storeDataDict;
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [headerModel.openedSubHeaders count]; i++) {
            myDict = [myDict objectForKey:[headerModel.openedSubHeaders objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
        cell.accessoryView=[[[HouraStoreCellView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, _storeTableView.bounds.size.width, 50) title:[[myDict allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] autorelease];
        return cell;
    } else if (tableView==_searchTableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [_resultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
    } else {
        return cell;
    }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    HouraStoreHeaderModel *headerModel = [self.headerInfoArray objectAtIndex:section];
    NSInteger height = 59.0 + ([headerModel.openedSubHeaders count]-1)*41.0;
    return height;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(tableView==_storeTableView){
        HouraStoreHeaderModel *headerModel = [self.headerInfoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        NSDictionary *myDict = _storeDataDict;
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [headerModel.openedSubHeaders count]; i++) {
            myDict = [myDict objectForKey:[headerModel.openedSubHeaders objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
        if ([[myDict objectForKey:[[myDict allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            [self cellOpened:indexPath];
        } else {
            [_activityIndicatorView startAnimating];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                     selector:@selector(_listProductsFoundedFinished:)
                                                         name:HouraSearchProductsDone
                                                       object:nil]; 
            NSString *searchString = [[myDict allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            searchString = [searchString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\u0022"];
            [_singleton.util beginSearchProducts:searchString context:@"2"];
        }
    } else if(tableView==_searchTableView){
        _searchBar.text = [_resultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [_searchBar resignFirstResponder];
        [_activityIndicatorView startAnimating];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(_listProductsFoundedFinished:)
                                                     name:HouraSearchProductsDone
                                                   object:nil]; 
        [_singleton.util beginSearchProducts:_searchBar.text context:@"2"];
    }
}

-(void)headerView:(HouraStoreHeaderView*)headerView headerOpened:(NSInteger)headerOpened {
    if (self.openSectionIndex!=NSNotFound) {
        [self closeAllHeaders];
    }
        //[self closeAllHeaders];
    HouraStoreHeaderModel *headerModel =nil;

    headerModel = [self.headerInfoArray objectAtIndex:headerOpened];
    headerModel.open = YES;
    headerModel.headerView.disclosureButton.selected = YES;

    NSDictionary *myDict = _storeDataDict;
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [headerModel.openedSubHeaders count]; i++) {
        myDict = [myDict objectForKey:[headerModel.openedSubHeaders objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    NSInteger countOfRowsToInsert = [[myDict allKeys] count];

    NSMutableArray *indexPathsToInsert = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < countOfRowsToInsert; i++) {
        [indexPathsToInsert addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:headerOpened]];
    }

    NSMutableArray *indexPathsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSInteger previousOpenSectionIndex = self.openSectionIndex;
    if (previousOpenSectionIndex != NSNotFound) {

        HouraStoreHeaderModel *previousHeaderModel = [self.headerInfoArray objectAtIndex:previousOpenSectionIndex];
        previousHeaderModel.open = NO;
        previousHeaderModel.headerView.disclosureButton.selected = NO;
        [previousHeaderModel.headerView toggleOpenWithUserAction:NO];
        NSInteger countOfRowsToDelete = [[[_storeDataDict objectForKey:previousHeaderModel.shelf ] allKeys] count];
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < countOfRowsToDelete; i++) {
            [indexPathsToDelete addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:previousOpenSectionIndex]];
        }
    }
    UITableViewRowAnimation insertAnimation;
    UITableViewRowAnimation deleteAnimation;
    if (previousOpenSectionIndex == NSNotFound || headerOpened < previousOpenSectionIndex) {
        insertAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimationTop;   
        deleteAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimationBottom;
    } else {
        insertAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimationBottom;
        deleteAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimationTop;
    }

    [_storeTableView beginUpdates];
    [_storeTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToDelete withRowAnimation:deleteAnimation];
    [_storeTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToInsert withRowAnimation:insertAnimation];
    [_storeTableView endUpdates];

    self.openSectionIndex = headerOpened;
}

-(void)headerView:(HouraStoreHeaderView*)headerView headerClosed:(NSInteger)headerClosed {

    HouraStoreHeaderModel *headerModel = [self.headerInfoArray objectAtIndex:headerClosed];

    headerModel.open = NO;
    headerModel.headerView.disclosureButton.selected = NO;
    [headerModel cleanOpenedSubHeaders];
    [self.headerInfoArray replaceObjectAtIndex:headerClosed withObject:headerModel];

    NSInteger countOfRowsToDelete = [_storeTableView numberOfRowsInSection:headerClosed];

    if (countOfRowsToDelete > 0) {
        NSMutableArray *indexPathsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < countOfRowsToDelete; i++) {
            [indexPathsToDelete addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:headerClosed]];
        }
        [_storeTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToDelete withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    }
    self.openSectionIndex = NSNotFound;
}

-(void)cellOpened:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    HouraStoreHeaderModel *headerModel = [self.headerInfoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    [self headerView:headerModel.headerView headerClosed:indexPath.section];
    [headerModel addOpenedSubHeaders:[[[_storeDataDict objectForKey:headerModel.shelf] allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [self.headerInfoArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section withObject:headerModel];
    headerModel = [self.headerInfoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    [self headerView:headerModel.headerView headerOpened:indexPath.section];
}

-(void)closeAllHeaders {
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [self.headerInfoArray count]; i++) {
        HouraStoreHeaderModel *headerModel = [self.headerInfoArray objectAtIndex:i];
        [self headerView:headerModel.headerView headerClosed:i];
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is, when I click a row, the section header update so it contains a new button with the row text. Then I dismiss the row and reload new datas in the section rows. I managed to handle the rows perfectly. But I can't find a way to get this header view updated.

Thx for any idea.

Comment: have you tried reloadSections:withRowAnimation:?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned, I've tried this and "reloadData"/"setNeedsDisplay".

Answer (score 2):

You just change it directly. I created an instance variable in the header file for a label that I will put in the header's view I'll create:

```
@interface MainViewController : UITableViewController {
    // creating my datasource array instance variable
    NSArray *_items;

    // this is the label I will add to the header view when I create it
    UILabel *_headerLabel;
}

@end
```

And in my tableView when they select a row I call a function that simply changes the text on the label:

```
@implementation MainViewController

- (id)init {
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

    / filling my datasource with test strings
    _items = @[@"one", @"two"];

    return self;
}

- (void)changeHeaderLabel:(NSString *)newLabel {
    // when this function gets called and is passed a string, I will simply
    // set the text on the label to the new string and viola!
    _headerLabel.text = newLabel;
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // this table will only have a single section for demo purposes
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // return the count of my datasource array
    return _items.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // attempt to create a cell by reusing one with a given identifier
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    // if I wasn't able to reuse one
    if (cell == nil) {
        // create one from scratch with that identifier
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    // now simply set the text on the cell from my data source array of strings
    cell.textLabel.text = _items[indexPath.row];

    // and return the cell
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // deselect the row so the cell automatically fades out after selection
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    // here you could do one of two things, either get a reference to the cell itself,
    // and then get the value stored in it's textLabel
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *newHeaderTitleString = selectedCell.textLabel.text;

    // OR you can get it right from your datasource
    NSString *newHeaderTitleString = _items[indexPath.row];

    // then just call the above function with the string as the single param
    [self changeHeaderLabel:newHeaderTitleString];
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // here I just create a view that will span the whole frame and is an arbitrary height
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 80)];
    // set the background color to clear
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // then I initialize my instance variable with a frame that's centered in the view
    // for aesthetic purposes
    _headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, self.view.frame.size.width - 10, 80)];

    // then I set the text color, add an autoresizing mask so if the view rotates
    // it still remains centered properly, set the text to some starting value, 
    // and add it to the headerView I previously created
    _headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    _headerLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    _headerLabel.text = @"Before";
    [headerView addSubview:_headerLabel];

    // then I return the headerView
    return headerView;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // return an arbitrary height here for testing
    return 80;
}
```

That results in the following:

[image]

[image]
[image]

If you have any questions let me know! This is just a quick example to demonstrate it, but you may want to customize the view in a different way altogether. This should at least solve your problem and give you a starting point to work from.

Comment: The question comes when changing more than just that, like subviess, etc. not only that but also changing height.

Comment: Give me an example, every attempt I've used to change the views has worked, whether it's telling the tableView to reload data or just changing it directly. Something you're doing isn't correct. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Sure. My headerview has a subview that is taller than the headerview initially. When I adjust the height of the headerview, to where it would show that subview, that subview isn't visible. It doesn't actually draw it on screen until you scroll somewhere. Same when I then adjust the height of that header to cover it again. You must scroll in order for it to hide itself.

Comment: Without any code I really couldn't help much. Why is the subview larger than the headerview initially? You should adjust the size of the subview before you add it.

Comment: You're right Mike, it's probably stupid and wasteful to even have that subview there until I'm actually needing it anyway. I'll try that approach, and report back. I have a feeling it will work. Best.

Comment: Let me know how it goes, hope I was of some help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` where you set the `row` property of the `NSIndexPath` passed in as `NSNotFound`? So reloading just the header of section 3, for instance would look like

```
NSIndexPath * headerIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: NSNotFound section:3];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[headerIndexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

I guarantee nothing, but I'm pretty sure it used to work before, because I used it a couple of times.

But even if it works, it's still a hack that might get broken by Apple any time.

## edit

Ok, never mind. I tried this with iOS 7 in Xcode 5 and for some reason, even with `NSNotFound` as the row number, it still reloads the whole sections (with all its cells). So this does not work any more, damn.