# Get a reference to viewForHeaderInSection

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, header

I need to update some viewForHeaderInSection.

I've see this question\answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21199295/618512

This is very similar to what I need, except I have many viewForHeaderInSection

Is there a way to get the reference if a visible header (without reload)?  This way, I can get element on it using view.tag"

Thanks

Comment: Why do I get negative rating?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can manage all your table view headers by yourself. That is, don't initialize a new one every time the tableview asks for one, but create all of them in viewDidLoad, store them in an NSArray, then just pass in the pointer when tableview asks for it.

Them you have complete access for each.

Comment: Hi  Thanks for your comment.  I'm more looking on a "on the fly" solution. :)

Comment: I agree that being able to grab it on the fly instead of storing the pointers would seem to be more efficient, but I'm not sure if that is possible. At least, I don't think you will be getting the same pointers, if you are generating a new view *each time* your table asks for a header view. Keep this solution as a backup, if you will.